# Product with digit in name not searched in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

In Magento, I have a product named "99VOLTS Magnetix - Dashboard Basic" ,but when I search 99Volts in Catalog search,the result "Your search returns no results." comes as output.
But If I search 99VOLTS Magnetix,then the product gets searched.

Please suggest how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: Is this product enabled? What is the visibility set to this product? Is the product in stock?

Comment: Yes I have about 20-25 products and all are enabled,Cache cleared,Reindexing Done. But still none of 25 products appears on Search.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Go to Admin->Config->catalog->catalog and in catalog search Tab,set "search type" to "Like". Earlier it was set to Fulltext,that's why 99volts was not searchable but 99VOLTS Magnetix was.

[image]